# NSFetchedResultsController change tracking across relationship

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, relationship

I have a model with two entities linked by a to-one relationship. I want to display in a TableView all EntityA objects where entityB.myIntAttribute equals a given value. This works when I create a FetchRequest for EntityA with the predicate @"entityB.myIntAttribute == aValue".

My problem is with change tracking. I have set a NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate delegate on the NSFetchedResultsController associated to the previous FetchRequest. This delegate works because it gets notified of a deletion if I set a new entityB that doesn't match the predicate on one of the results. But if I change directly the value of myIntAttribute on the entityB object so that the predicate result changes, my delegate is not notified of the change.

Does NSFetchedResultsController change tracking work with a predicate that goes across a relationship ? How can the FetchedResultController recompute the predicate after modification of an attribute of the relationship ?

Comment: See my answer below, the comment won't let me add enough characters

Answer (score -1):

Are you implementing all of the following methods in your delegate:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
```